# Brew not installing the latest version

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to get that latest version of python on a Mac Mountain Lion. But the latest version is 2.7.4, but when I run brew install python it downloads the 2.7.2. What is going on?

```
brew install python
```

> ==> Downloading http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
>   File already downloaded in /Users/pietro/Library/Caches/Homebrew
>   ==> Patching patching file Lib/whichdb.py
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 91 with fuzz 1.
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2 --enable-shared
>   ==> make
>   ==> make install
>   ==> Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz
>   File already downloaded in /Users/pietro/Library/Caches/Homebrew
>   ==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python setup.py install
>   ==> Caveats
>   A "distutils.cfg" has been written to:   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/distutils specifing the
>   install-scripts folder as:   /usr/local/share/python
>
> If you install Python packages via "python setup.py install",
>   easy_install, pip, any provided scripts will go into the
>   install-scripts folder above, so you may want to add it to your PATH.
>
> Distribute has been installed, so easy_install is available. To update
>   distribute itself outside of Homebrew:
>       /usr/local/share/python/easy_install pip
>       /usr/local/share/python/pip install --upgrade distribute
>
> See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python
>   ==> Summary
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2: 4803 files, 81M, built in 2.4 minutes

Comment: have you tried to delete python and reinstall it as said in [link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19377) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did, and it would re-install 2.7.2. What really helped was what mipadi suggested to brew up. After that it all worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you updated Homebrew lately (by running `brew up`)? 2.7.4 is the current Python version in Homebrew.

Comment: Bingo! Yes, this made it.